# Pandas - Dataframe - Conditional add

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I want to add a new column in my data frame. I have a list of events and if any of these is different from 0 the value of the row in the new column should be 1.

I think it should be very simple, but i am fairly new to python.

The dataframe looks like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,1,2,3],"Date":["01/01/2019","01/01/2019","02/01/2019","02/01/2019"],"Event_1":[1,0,0,0],"Event_2":[1,0,0,1],"Event_3":[0,1,0,1],"Other":[0,0,0,1]})

print(df)
ID    Date         Event_1 Event_2 Event_3 Other
1     01/01/2019   1       1       0       0
1     01/01/2019   0       0       1       0
2     02/01/2019   0       0       0       0
3     02/01/2019   0       1       1       1
```

And should look like this:

```py
ID    Date         Event_1 Event_2 Event_3 Other Conditional_row
1     01/01/2019   1       1       0       0     1
1     01/01/2019   0       0       1       0     1
2     02/01/2019   0       0       0       0     0
3     02/01/2019   0       1       1       1     1
```

What is the easiest way of doing it? What is the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your data frame is stored in an object called `df`. I believe this is the most efficient way to do this:

```py
df["Conditional_row"] = 0
df.loc[df[["Event_1","Event_2","Event_3","Other"]].sum(axis=1) > 0, "Conditional_row"] = 1
```

The output looks like this:

```py
print(df)
   ID        Date  Event_1  Event_2  Event_3  Other  Conditional_row
0   1  01/01/2019        1        1        0      0                1
1   1  01/01/2019        0        0        1      0                1
2   2  02/01/2019        0        0        0      0                0
3   3  02/01/2019        0        1        1      1                1
```

What I did here was:

1. I created a new column filled with zeroes.
2. I selected all the rows where the row-wise sum of the columns in the list `["Event_1","Event_2","Event_3","Other"]` is greater than 1.
3. The column `"Conditional_row"` of the rows that meet that condition are updated with the value 1.

The code `df[["Event_1","Event_2","Event_3","Other"]].sum(axis=1) > 0` is called a `mask` and it returns a boolean array (a vector filled with `True` and `False` values). It selects all the rows where the return value is `True`. Typically, slicing using boolean arrays is the most efficient way to manipulate data frames.

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter` + `any`

Since all non-zero integers are *Truthy* in Python, calling `any` directly on your DataFrame results in the correct mask.  Since you want an integer output, we can use a memory efficient `view` to view the boolean mask as a integer type.

---

```
df.filter(like="Event").any(1).view('i1')
```

```
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    1
dtype: int8
```

Comment: Got it almost working. It doesn't raise an error now. But for some reason it sets all values to 0

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `DataFrame.filter`, `eq` and `any`

First we `filter` the columns which start with `Event` or `Other`. Then we check if `any` of the rows are `eq` (equal) to `1`:

```
df['Conditional_row'] = df.filter(regex="^Event|^Other").eq(1).any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

```
   ID        Date  Event_1  Event_2  Event_3  Other  Conditional_row
0   1  01/01/2019        1        1        0      0                1
1   1  01/01/2019        0        0        1      0                1
2   2  02/01/2019        0        0        0      0                0
3   3  02/01/2019        0        1        1      1                1
```

Comment: I have a list of rows in:
`event_list = ("event_1","event_2","event_2","event_3","other")`
And when i substitute `like='Event` for `event list` i get:
`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: See my edit which includes checking for column `Other` as well. @JesperMølgaard

Answer (score 1):

Or use:

```
df['Conditional_row'] = df[['Event_1', 'Event_2', 'Event_3', 'Other']].ne(0).any(1).astype(int)
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ID        Date  Event_1  Event_2  Event_3  Conditional_row
0   1  01/01/2019        1        1        0                1
1   1  01/01/2019        0        0        1                1
2   2  02/01/2019        0        0        0                0
3   3  02/01/2019        0        1        1                1
```

Comment: It looks like it could be easy to implement, but for me that raises a TypeError: `Cannot convert bool to numpy.ndarray`

My list of rows is in: `event_list = ("event_1","event_2","event_2","event_3","other")` And i tried to substitute ['Event_1', 'Event_2', 'Event_3'] for `event_list`

Comment: @JesperMølgaard Added other